# SQL Server job run as dbo fails on raiserror with log

Tags: sql-server

I have created a simple job in SQL Server Agent, with following step T-SQL command:

```
declare @msg varchar(100) = 'My job failed'
raiserror (@msg,10,1) WITH LOG
```

I have specified *Run as user* `dbo` in Advanced page of the job step editor window.

I have configured an alert for the job (to send an email). I get an email

> [The job failed.] SQL Server Job System: 'test raiserror' completed on \server

but the email does not contain the error message, because of this (from job history):

> Executed as user: dbo. Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 2778). The step failed.

`dbo` user is system administrator. What shall I do to make it work?

I have also tried this:

```
sp_addmessage  @msgnum=99001 ,@severity= 16, @msgtext= Job errror' , @with_log=  'TRUE', @replace= 'replace' 
raiserror (99001,10,1)
```

but unless the `sp_addmessage` is called before the job starts, the job prints this error:

> Executed as user: dbo. User does not have permission to perform this action. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15247)  Error 99001, severity 10, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage. The step failed.

And when I call the `sp_addmessage` outside of the job, then the job history prints:

> Executed as user: dbo. User does not have permission to perform this action. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15247) Job error [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 99001). The step failed.

Thank you very much

Comment: `dbo` and `sysadmin` are **not** synonymous. A `dbo` is a Database Owner; they are at database and user level; a `sysadmin` is a system administrator, which is a server level permission and login based.

Comment: dbo user of the DB i am running the step on has login sa. Which has sysadmin (server) role

Comment: I ha te the say it, but if the error you're getting is *Executed as user: dbo. Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 2778). The step failed.* then no, `dbo` does not have sysadmin rights.

Comment: Make sure the job owned by sa.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes it is

Comment: @Larnu what do you suggest then? I have also run the job as another user with granted ALTER TRACE, but it didnt work either

Comment: Is the SQL Server Agent service account a sysadmim role member?

Comment: how do I find out?

Comment: OR how do I add sysadmin rights to the dbo user ?

Comment: What is the result for `SELECT sysadmin FROM sys.syslogins WHERE [name] = '[SQL Agent Service Account]';`? (Obviously replacing the name of with your Service Accounts name).

Comment: Im not sure which account it is, sorry :-( Both sa, NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT return 1